# Segfault when using aiohttp.ClientSession and asyncio.wait

Tags: python, aiohttp, python-asyncio

About three months ago, I wrote some code along these lines:

```py
import asyncio
import aiohttp

async def get(client, url):
    return await client.get(url)

async def coro():
    client = aiohttp.ClientSession()

    tasks = [
        asyncio.create_task(get(client, 'https://www.google.com')),
        asyncio.create_task(get(client, 'https://www.stackoverflow.com'))
    ]

    _, tasks = await asyncio.wait(tasks, return_when=asyncio.FIRST_COMPLETED)
    _, tasks = await asyncio.wait(tasks, return_when=asyncio.FIRST_COMPLETED)

    await client.close()

    return 'timey-wimey'

result = asyncio.run(coro())

print(result)
```

Obviously there's a lot of code missing from this MVP, but the overall structure of the code was basically this. And it was running fine.

Now I got back to it after not touching it for three months and suddenly it crashes *without stacktrace*. The process just dies (with exit code 245, according to my IDE). I put together this MVP, ran it, and my IDE reports:

> Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV)

Am I using the asyncio tools wrongly here?

After trying to fix it, I replaced `result = asyncio.run(coro())` with

```py
loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
loop.run_until_complete(coro())
```

and my real code runs fine again. Unless I add

```py
loop.close()
```

in which case it crashes again.

Comment: It can be related to python upgrade.
Say, sometimes virtualenv should be recreated.

Comment: great point @AndrewSvetlov, it was in my case.